# Duplicate array to new array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem in my java code. I would like to copy and duplicate an array to one new array. It always gave me error on java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

code :

```
public void SetCard(int usrSet)
    {
            //define 52card with number and shape
            String[] cards = {"1a","1d", "1h", "1s", "2a", "2d", "2h", "2s"};
            //set to an global array
            deckCards = null;
            //deckCards = new String[cards.length];
            //deckCards = cards;

            int setLength = cards.length;
            String temp = "";
            if (usrSet >= 1)
            {
                    setLength = setLength * usrSet - 1;
                    int a = 0;
                    deckCards = new String[setLength];
                    System.out.println("Deck Cards now is " + deckCards.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < usrSet; i++)
                    {
                            for(int j = 0; j < cards.length; j++)
                            {
                                    temp = cards[j];
                                    System.out.println("Position SetL = "+ a + "J is " + j + "Temp = "+ temp);
                                    deckCards[a] = temp;
                                    a++;
                            }
                    }
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deckCards));
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the "- 1" in:
`setLength = setLength * usrSet - 1;`
so it becomes
`setLength = setLength * usrSet;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will give the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if usrSet is greater than 1. 
If your intention is to just make a copy of an array, I am not sure why you are doing so many things. Probably the below code may suffice:

`String[] deckCards = new String[setLength];
    for(int j = 0; j < cards.length;  j++){
        temp = cards[j];
        deckCards[j]= temp;
    }`

If you are at liberty to use other api, try exploring java.util.Arrays

Comment: Why use `temp` at all?

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is

```
deckCards = (String[])cards.clone();
```

`clone()` of an array type [is public](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7).